# Manipulating/view postmeta remotely

Tags: rest-api, xml-rpc

I'm new to WordPress development. I'm using a plugin, "Tribe Events," that stores event venues and organizers associated with an event in the `wp_postmeta` table and I want to be able to easily access and manipulate the data associated with an event. But apparently, the plugin does not provide a REST API (the `tribe_events` post type doesn't show with a call to `wp-json/wp/v2/types`). And from what I can tell, XMLRPC does not allow you to access postmeta data either.

So what are my best options at this point? Use mysql API? Roll my own API for the plugin? These ideas seem a little too ambitious. Alternatively, I guess I can just do what I've been doing which is use `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` to automate the creation/deletion/editing of posts (which is kind of crazy).

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the arguments of the post type to enable the REST API:

```
function wpd_tribe_events_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'tribe_events' == $post_type ) {
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpd_tribe_events_args', 20, 2 );
```